# Cross-platform issues or what is the alternative to QtConcurrent :: run?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qt4.8

I need to run the function asynchronously in a separate thread, I used `QtConcurrent :: run` everything was fine when I tested windows, but as soon as I ran the same code on linux, it started to work synchronously. Using qt4.8 and c++98 :c

Testable code:

```
void myRunFunction(QString name)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        qDebug() << name << " " << i << "from" << QThread::currentThread();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFuture<void> t1 = QtConcurrent::run(myRunFunction, QString("A"));
    QFuture<void> t2 = QtConcurrent::run(myRunFunction, QString("B"));
    QFuture<void> t3 = QtConcurrent::run(myRunFunction, QString("C"));

    t1.waitForFinished();
    t2.waitForFinished();
    t3.waitForFinished();

    return a.exec();
}
```

What I get in the console:

```
"A" 0 from QThread (0x11a78f8, name = "Thread (pooled)")
...
"A" 1000 from QThread (0x11a78f8, name = "Thread (pooled)")
after
"B" 0 from QThread (0x11a78f8, name = "Thread (pooled)")
...
"B" 1000 from QThread (0x11a78f8, name = "Thread (pooled)")
etc
```

Tell me how to fix this, or what else can you try? i wanted to try [QtConcurrent::run(QThreadPool *pool, Function function, ...)](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run-1) but qt4.8 doesn't have it

Comment: What value is returned by [`QThreadPool::globalInstance()->maxThreadCount()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#maxThreadCount-prop)?

Comment: Are you using a virtual machine?

Comment: Did you tried the standard library equivalent? `std::future` `std::thread` etc.. However QT works very smoothly on Linux (I use it all days, I am on KDE plasma just now), so I expect some other issue

Comment: @AdrianMaire i use qt4.8 and c++98 ><

Comment: My condolences.

Comment: @vahancho yes, virtualbox 6.1. It somehow affects?

Comment: @G.M. 1, how to fix it?

Comment: Try e.g. `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(4)` .

Comment: @G.M. You are right. Write an answer, I confirm the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments it appears that the number of threads in the global `QThreadPool` instance may be limited, by default, to a single thread due to constraints imposed on the VM.

To counter that you can simply set the thread count explicitly using...

```
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(4);
```